# How can I force Python code to read input files again without rebooting my computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, garbage-collection

I am scanning through a large number of files looking for some markers.   I am starting to be really confident that once I have run through the code one time Python is not rereading the actual files from disk.  I find this behavior strange because I was told that one reason I needed to structure my file access in the manner I have is so that the handle and file content is flushed.  But that can't be.

There are 9,568 file paths in the list I am reading from.  If I shut down Python and reboot my computer it takes roughly **6 minutes** to read the files and determine if there is anything returned from the regular expression.

However, if I run the code a second time it takes about **36 seconds**.  Just for grins, the average document has 53,000 words.

Therefore I am concluding that Python still has access to the file it read in the first iteration.

I want to also observe that the first time I do this I can hear the disk spin (E:\ - Python is on C:).  E is just a spinning disk with 126 MB cache - I don't think the cache is big enough to hold the contents of these files.  When I do it later I do not hear the disk spin.

Here is the code

```
import re
test_7A_re = re.compile(r'\n\s*ITEM\s*7\(*a\)*[.]*\s*-*\s*QUANT.*\n',re.IGNORECASE)
no7a = []
for path in path_list:
    path = path.strip()
    with open(path,'r') as fh:
        string = fh.read()
    items = [item for item in re.finditer(test_7A_re,string)]
    if len(items) == 0:
        no7a.append(path)
        continue
```

I care about this for a number of reasons, one is that I was thinking about using multi-processing.  But if the bottleneck is reading in the files I don't see that I will gain much. I also think this is a problem because I would be worried about the file being modified and not having the most recent version of the file available.

I am tagging this 2.7 because I have no idea if this behavior is persistent across versions.

To confirm this behavior I modified my code to run as a .py file, and added some timing code.  I then rebooted my computer - the first time it ran it took 5.6 minutes and the second time (without rebooting) the time was 36 seconds.  Output is the same in both cases.

**The really interesting thing is that even if shut down IDLE (but do not reboot my computer) it still takes 36 seconds to run the code**.

All of this suggests to me that the files are not read from disk after the first time - this is amazing behavior to me but it seems dangerous.

To be clear, the results are the same - I believe given the timing tests I have run and the fact that I do not hear the disk spinning that somehow the files are still accessible to Python.

Comment: What do you mean, "files are not read after the first time"?  Wouldn't you get wrong results if they weren't read?

Comment: Have you checked if the memory allocated to Python is increasing w/ the second iteration? As an experiment, you could try running `gc.collect` at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: I actually have been wrestling with this for a while and have tried all kinds of gc tricks that I could find.  None worked and so right now @user6401364 seems to have the best explanation.  I am going to test this by adding a newline to each of the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by caching in Windows. It is not related to Python.

In order to stop Windows from caching your reads:

1. Disable paging file in Windows and fill the RAM up to 90%
2. Use some tool to disable file caching in Windows [like this one](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897561).
3. Run your code on a Linux VM on your Windows machine that has limited RAM. In Linux you can control the caching much better
4. Make the files much bigger, so that they won't fit in cache

Comment: That is really cool.  I will have to poke around some more I would not have thought this was driven by windows.  So you are saying that Python asks the OS for the file and the OS checks to see if it has a cached copy - if so then the cached copy is passed to Python, otherwise it fetches the file?

Comment: exactly, and the good part is that if the file change for any reason windows will handle providing python with the updated file . So you python code is always running exactly the same way but windows on the second time give it the file from memory instead from the disk directly

Comment: Another way around it is to read different files, to fill up the cache and cause it to expire the file you wanted to test against

Comment: Well it is not a problem if Windows is passing the most recent version of the file, as a matter of fact I like the speed gain but was concerned, for obvious reasons, about the potential consequences.

Comment: I think you are saying that I cannot force a read from disk unless the file is changed.  Python passes the path - Windows knows it has a reference to the string - checks the date modifed - sees that there is no change and passes its references to Python?

Comment: if the file is changed you are sure that python will read from disk . also you can force it by preventing windows from caching your files or filling the windows cache with something else as @SimonFraser suggested just copy large file around (bigger than your ram size) before running the python code and by that way you fill the cache with un-relevant info and on next run python will be forced to read from disk

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why this is a problem. I'm not 100% certain of how Windows handles file cache invalidation, but unless the "Last modified time" changes, you and I and Windows would assume that the file still holds the same content. If the file holds the same content, I don't see why reading from cache can be a problem.

I'm pretty sure that if you change the last modified date, say, by opening the file for write access then closing it right away, Windows will hold sufficient doubts over the file content and invalidate the cache.

Comment: It was a problem because I did not understand that Windows would keep track of the file and substitute the new file if the file was modified.  Now that I asked the question after carefully confirming that my files were not seeming to be read again and I have an answer it is no-longer a problem. But surely you can see that this would be a problem without the information that the file access is being managed by my OS.

Comment: I understand and admire your desire to understand what is going on "under the hood", even from a high level language like python. Just keep in mind that digging will eventually lead you to OS internals, which should be expected to be close to optimal for every major OS. This should keep you from the urge to mold the cache inner working to your code instead of shaping your code around the existing cache.